# Resizable panel with movable label in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, position, label, panel, drag

Hi i am developing a flex page in which i have a panel which is dynamically created, with a label in it.The panel is resizable, so while we dragging for maximising it, the label position is not changing.how to alter the label position according to the panel size.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You say label position so it sems that it is sizing!? so position the label within the panel or in a container like VBox = w-100% / h-100% & center the label which will have already w-100% / h=100% or vertical Center - horizontal Center. regards aktell

Comment: This is my code.What value i have to give in label.x and label.y

label.height=12; label.width = 10; label.text="test";
panel.add(label);